# Adding vlines to a density plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, k-means, density-plot, geom-vline

I am trying to add vlines to a density plot in shiny for R. For reproducible purposes, I will use the iris data set. The data is clustered using kmeans from the cluster package. Outliers are located by measuring distances from the centers of clusters. Then I wish to create a density plot that has vlines and labels for each of the outliers.

The code works outside of shiny. Inside my shiny app, I get an error message: *Error in [: invalid subscript type 'list'.* I have tried unlist and making the outliers a variety of other forms and still get the list error. How do I add the vlines?

**Global**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)
library(shiny)

require(iris)
```

**UI**

```
ui <- fluidPage({
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
  )
})
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output){
  
  ClusterData <- reactive({
    iris[,1:4]
  })
  
  # need to keep row numbers for outlier labels
  ClusterData2 <- reactive({
    ClusterData2 <- data.frame(ClusterData())
    
    row.names(ClusterData2) <- 1:nrow(ClusterData2)
    
    return(ClusterData2)
  })
  

  # scale the iris data
  ScaledData <- reactive({
    scale(ClusterData2())
  })
  
  # kmeans clustering
  final <- reactive({
    kmeans(ScaledData(), 3, nstart = 25)
  })
  
  # find centers
  states.centers <- reactive({
    final()$centers[final()$cluster, ]
  })
  
  # find outliers
  distances <- reactive({
    sqrt(rowSums((ScaledData() - states.centers())^2))
  })
  
  # bind distances back to data
  outliers <- reactive({
    cbind(ClusterData(), Distance = distances())
  })
  
  # bind cluster number to data
  clusterMember <- reactive({
    cbind(outliers(), clusterNum = final()$cluster)
  })
  
  # turn into data frame
  clusterMember2 <- reactive({
    as.data.frame(clusterMember())
  })
  
  # find points that are their own cluster
  dist0 <- reactive({
    clusterMember() %>%
      filter(distances() == 0)
  })
  
  # arrange distances largest to smallest
  distArrange <- reactive({
    clusterMember() %>%
      arrange(desc(Distance))
  })
  
  # find top 5 outliers
  filtTop5 <- reactive({
    distArrange()[1:5,]
  })
  
  # bind outliers and single clusters together
  AllOutliers <- reactive({
    rbind(filtTop5(), dist0())
    
  })
  
  
  # for density plot: vlines and labels
  lines_amt <- reactive({
    data.frame(vlines = (clusterMember2()$Petal.Length[c(AllOutliers())]), labels = c(AllOutliers()))
  })
  
  
  
  ########## output
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ClusterData() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
      geom_density(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.4) #+
    geom_vline(data = lines_amt(), aes(xintercept = get(vlines)))
  })
  
  
}
```

**Run App**

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you.

The plot should look like the link.

[PetalLengthDensityPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByOod.png)

Comment: The code you have for your `lines_amt` doesn't seem to work. `AllOutliers()` is returning a data.frame but you seem to be treating it like a regular vector. I'm not sure what you are expecting `clusterMember2()$Petal.Length[c(AllOutliers())])` to return.

Comment: I think that is the issue, @MrFlick. Thank you. I attached an image of what I'm trying to do to my question. I want a list of the Outlier row numbers. Then use those row numbers to draw vlines at the appropriate spots on a density plot and label each vline with the row number.

Comment: Okay, deleted my previous comments, but I think you don't need the ```lines_amt()``` reactive. I think you can just use this line instead of your current ```geom_vline()```:   ```geom_vline(xintercept = AllOutliers()$Petal.Length)```. This should fix and provide a graph similar to your example, minus the labels that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it all sorted out. Essentially I removed your `lines_amt()` reactive, and replaced `geom_vline()`, while also adding an `annotate()` for the labels:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage({
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
  )
})

server <- function(input, output){
  
  ClusterData <- reactive({
    iris[,1:4]
  })
  
  # need to keep row numbers for outlier labels
  ClusterData2 <- reactive({
    ClusterData2 <- data.frame(ClusterData())
    
    row.names(ClusterData2) <- 1:nrow(ClusterData2)
    
    return(ClusterData2)
  })
  
  
  # scale the iris data
  ScaledData <- reactive({
    scale(ClusterData2())
  })
  
  # kmeans clustering
  final <- reactive({
    kmeans(ScaledData(), 3, nstart = 25)
  })
  
  # find centers
  states.centers <- reactive({
    final()$centers[final()$cluster, ]
  })
  
  # find outliers
  distances <- reactive({
    sqrt(rowSums((ScaledData() - states.centers())^2))
  })
  
  # bind distances back to data
  outliers <- reactive({
    cbind(ClusterData(), Distance = distances())
  })
  
  # bind cluster number to data
  clusterMember <- reactive({
    cbind(outliers(), clusterNum = final()$cluster)
  })
  
  # turn into data frame
  clusterMember2 <- reactive({
    as.data.frame(clusterMember())
  })
  
  # find points that are their own cluster
  dist0 <- reactive({
    clusterMember() %>%
      filter(distances() == 0)
  })
  
  # arrange distances largest to smallest
  distArrange <- reactive({
    clusterMember() %>%
      arrange(desc(Distance))
  })
  
  # find top 5 outliers
  filtTop5 <- reactive({
    distArrange()[1:5,]
  })
  
  # bind outliers and single clusters together
  AllOutliers <- reactive({
    rbind(filtTop5(), dist0())
    
  })
  
  
  # for density plot: vlines and labels #Made the lines and labels without this
  # lines_amt <- reactive({
  #   data.frame(vlines = (clusterMember2()$Petal.Length[c(AllOutliers()$Petal.Length)]), labels = c(AllOutliers()))
  # })
  
  
  
  ########## output
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ClusterData() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
      geom_density(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.4) +
      # geom_vline(xintercept = lines_amt()$vlines)
      geom_vline(xintercept = AllOutliers()$Petal.Length)+ #Used this in place of your current geom_vline() 
      annotate("text", x = AllOutliers()$Petal.Length, #Added this to add the text
      y = 0,
      label = rownames(AllOutliers()),
      hjust = -1,
      vjust = -1)
    
    # geom_vline(data = lines_amt(), aes(xintercept = get(vlines)))
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @Sildentdevildoll, thank you so much! This is perfect. I would send you a pizza if that wasn't weird.